# Database locking when deleting rows from large table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL InnoDB table with about 11.8 million rows. Each row has a foreign key referencing the primary key of another table. Whenever I need to delete from the table where said foreign key is of a specific value (e.g. `delete from <table_name> where <foreign_key_column> = <some_value>`) then the query takes a long ass time (a few minutes) to execute and completely locks up the database meanwhile. Is there a way I can speed this up or at least have the database not lock completely while the query executes?

Comment: "**InnoDB checks UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints row-by-row**. When performing foreign key checks, **InnoDB sets shared row-level locks on child or parent records it has to look at.** InnoDB checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred to transaction commit." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html .. meaning without correct indexing on foreign key this will be slow because a full table scan is needed and locks the table.

Comment: So i have a feeling you didn't properly put indexes on the parent and child table.. Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` statements for every table involved in the question